# iOS: How to check if a XMPPStream timed out

Tags: ios, connection, timeout, xmpp, chat

I am developing a chat application and using https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/ library to develop the app.

I would like to handle connection time out situations ,
I have used 
 - (BOOL)connectWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout error:(NSError **)errPtr function to connect to server .

Here i have provided 60 seconds as the time out interval. Can any one suggest me how to handle time out ?
IS there any delegates gets called when time out happens ?

Thanks,
Bhat

Comment: xmppStreamDidDisconnect:withError:

Comment: also xmppStreamConnectDidTimeout: